# Read Text From Web Page

Tags: c#, html

Please note: I do **not** want to read the HTML content of a page, rather, I am looking to read the text from a web page. Imagine the following example, if you will -

A PHP script echos back "Hello User X" onto the current page, so that the user is now looking at a page (mainly blank) with the words "Hello User X" printed in the top left corner. From my C# Application, I would like to read the text onto a string.

```
String strPageData = functionToReadPageData("http://www.myURL.com/file.php");

Console.WriteLine(strPageData); // Outputs "Hello User X" to the Console.
```

#### In VB6 I was able to do this by using the following API:

1. InternetOpen
2. InternetOpenURL
3. InternetReadFile
4. InternetCloseHandle

I attempted to port my VB6 code to C# but I am having no luck - so I would very much appreciate a C# method for completing the above task.

Comment: How do you define text? Is the link text also part of text? or only strings that are inside a <div> or <span> tag? What about button label text?

Comment: @Phillip Look here: http://nanisolutions.zxq.net/PHP/phpindex.php?page=customerid&customerid=mmm

I want only "hah mmm hdhd jkdjd 0 0" to be returned.

Comment: Please don't prefix your questions with "C#" and such. You've already used the tags for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any parts of the .NET framework that lets you automagically extract all the text from a HTML file. I very much doubt it exists.

You can try the HtmlAgilityPack (3rd party) for accessing text elements etc in a HTML document.

You will still need to write logic to find the correct HTML element though. A HTML page like this:

```
<html>
     <body>Some text</body>
</html>
```

Then you would need to locate the body tag with an xpath  and read its content.

```
HtmlNode body = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//body");
string bodyContent = body.InnerText;
```

Following that pattern you can read every element on the page. You might need to do some post processing to remove breaks, comments etc.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: This is very confusing for me, I am not able to figure out how to make this work properly. I will keep at it though and let you know if I can get anything to work ... I would rather not have to bother with the HTML at all though.

Comment: I will use this method for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I'm surprised no one has mentioned using `microsoft.mshtml` which works rather well for this sort of thing. You'll need to add a reference to `microsoft.mshtml`

[Right click on `References` in your project in `Solution Explorer`. Then click `Add Reference...`. In `Assemblies` type in search 'HTML' and you'll see `Microsoft.mshtml`.]

then:

```
using System.Net;
using mshtml;

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var s = client.DownloadString(@"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264659/read-text-from-web-page");
    var htmldoc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)new HTMLDocument();
    htmldoc2.write(s);
    var plainText = htmldoc2.body.outerText;
    Console.WriteLine(plainText);
}
```

Which will return the, "OuterText" of the webpage, which is basically the text displayed when you visit it with a web browser. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebClient class to do this.

Comment: I had checked out this class a while ago - but I was only able to read the HTML, not the actual text on the page. Any ideas as to what I may have been doing wrong?

Comment: +1. Use the WebClient class and strip out the text using a HTML Parser. If you dont want to go the html parser or RegEx route you could save the HTML and using IE or Safari get the plain text using javascript eg: document.body.innerText

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help you.

```
string result = "";
try
{
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(IOParams.ConfigPath +"SUCCESSEMPTMP.HTML"))
     {
           result = sr.ReadToEnd();
           result = result.Replace("<body/>", "<body>");
           result = result.Replace("</body>", "<body>");
           List<string> body = new List<string>(result.Split(new string[] { "<body>" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
           if (body.Count > 2)
           {
                result = body[1];
           }
      }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}

return result;
```